# Where can I learn about perl6 Type variables (::T)

Tags: raku

I need to use perl6 type variables. It seems that the definitive manual is here http://www.jnthn.net/papers/2008-yapc-eu-perl6types.pdf, which is concise and v. useful in so far as it goes.

Is there anything more comprehensive or authoritative that I can be pointed to?

Comment: That's neither definitive nor a manual, that's the slides for a 10 years old presentation (so it's probably hopelessly out of date). https://docs.perl6.org/ looks like official documentation. As for types: https://docs.perl6.org/language/typesystem.

Comment: I looked at it, curious how out of date it was, and was surprised to discover that - aside from the notes about things not being implemented yet - it is still mostly correct. Agree it's neither definitive nor a manual, though. :-)

Comment: yes - sorry should have marked that as "the only thing that I could dig up" rather than the tongue in cheek "definitive manual" ;-) ... nevertheless it worked for me and has stood the test of time

Comment: I like books a lot, and would advise to deep into "Perl 6 Deep Dive" ( https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/perl-6-deep-dive ), especially page 51 and further, "Typed variables" in a chapter "Working with variables and Built-in Data types", that explains variable types and lots more in rather easy to understand words. By the way, the same for "Think Perl 6" ( https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/think-perl-6/9781491980545/ ), that has as its second chapter: "Variables, Expressions, and Statements". Also on page 239 and further a chapter on making your own types, "Programm

Comment: I also like books -perhaps this is a perl thing... some great tips and, yes, Think Perl6 already in my library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I like to think of it is that `Int` is really short for `::Int`.

So most of the time that you are talking about a type, you can add the `::` to the front of it.

Indeed if you have a string and you want to use it to get the type with the same short name you use `::(…)`

```perl6
my $type-name = 'Int';
say 42 ~~ ::($type-name); # True
```

---

The thing is that using a type in a signature is already used to indicate that the parameter is of that type.

```perl6
->   Int $_   {…}
```

Any unsigiled identifier in a signature is seen as the above, so the following throws an error if there isn't a `foo` type.

```perl6
->   foo   {…}
```

What you probably want in the situation above is for `foo` to be a sigiless variable. So you have to add a `\` to the front. (Inside of the block you just use `foo`.)

```perl6
->   \foo   {…}
```

---

So if you wanted to add a feature where you capture the type, you have to do something different than just use an identifier. So obviously adding `::` to the front was chosen.

```perl6
->   ::foo   { say foo }
```

If you call it with the number `42`, it will print `(Int)`.

---

You can combine these

```perl6
-> Real ::Type \Value {…}
```

The above only accepts a real number (all numerics except Complex), aliases the type to `Type`, and aliases the number to `Value`

```perl6
sub example ( Real ::Type \Value ) {
  my Type $var = Value;

  say Type;
  say Value;
}
```

```
> example 42;
(Int)
42

> example ''
Type check failed in binding to parameter 'Value'; expected Real but got Str ("")
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1

> example 42e0
(Num)
42
```

---

This is also used in roles.

```perl6
role Foo[ Real ::Type \Value ] {
  has Type $.foo = Value; # constrained to the same type as Value
}
class Example does Foo[42] {}

say Example.new( :foo(128) ).foo; # 128
say Example.new().foo;            # 42

say Example.new( :foo(1e0) );     # Type check error
```

You can of course leave off any part that you don't need.

```perl6
role Foo[::Type] {…}
```

Comment: thank you Brad for taking this one or two levels higher - this is very inspiring for someone like me who is trying to bootstrap up from "meat+potatoes" coding [aka perl6 is awesome]

Answer (score 5):

What you're referring to is called "type capture" in perl6, here's two pages about them:

- Type Captures in function/method signatures: https://docs.perl6.org/type/Signature#index-entry-Type_Capture_%28signature%29
- Type Captures in Roles: https://docs.perl6.org/language/typesystem#index-entry-Type_Capture_%28role%29

Hope that helps!